# MSI GE72 / Ubuntu 16.04 - No network devices available

Tags: networking, drivers

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my new MSI GE72 and I got problem with my network devices. I have WIN10 on this machine so it is not hardware problem.
I will put some listings.

```
lshw -C network

  *-network UNCLAIMED     
   description: Network controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: 10
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:df300000-df301fff


*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: Qualcomm Atheros
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   version: 10
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:df200000-df23ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
```

---

```
lspci -vnn | grep Network

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
```

---

```
lsmod

Module                  Size  Used by
bnep                   20480  2
msi_wmi                16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 msi_wmi
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             172032  0
kvm                   536576  1 kvm_intel
snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
snd_hda_intel          36864  3
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core           73728  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               106496  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
aesni_intel           167936  0
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20480  2 aesni_intel,ablk_helper
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
uvcvideo               90112  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
joydev                 20480  0
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2
input_leds             16384  0
videodev              176128  4 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
snd                    81920  17 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
serio_raw              16384  0
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
soundcore              16384  1 snd
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
mei_me                 36864  0
mei                    98304  1 mei_me
shpchp                 36864  0
hci_uart               77824  0
btbcm                  16384  2 btusb,hci_uart
btqca                  16384  1 hci_uart
btintel                16384  2 btusb,hci_uart
bluetooth             520192  11 bnep,btbcm,btqca,btrtl,btusb,hci_uart,btintel
intel_lpss_acpi        16384  0
tpm_crb                16384  0
intel_lpss             16384  1 intel_lpss_acpi
acpi_pad               20480  0
mac_hid                16384  0
acpi_als               16384  0
kfifo_buf              16384  1 acpi_als
industrialio           57344  2 acpi_als,kfifo_buf
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
usbhid                 49152  0
nouveau              1495040  0
i915_bpo             1261568  3
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
ttm                    94208  1 nouveau
intel_ips              20480  1 i915_bpo
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 i915_bpo,nouveau
psmouse               126976  0
drm_kms_helper        147456  2 i915_bpo,nouveau
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ahci                   36864  4
drm                   360448  7 ttm,i915_bpo,drm_kms_helper,nouveau
libahci                32768  1 ahci
wmi                    20480  3 msi_wmi,mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  40960  3 i915_bpo,msi_wmi,nouveau
pinctrl_sunrisepoint    28672  0
i2c_hid                20480  0
pinctrl_intel          20480  1 pinctrl_sunrisepoint
hid                   118784  2 i2c_hid,usbhid
fjes                   28672  0
```

---

```
cat /etc/lsb-release; uname -a

    DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
    DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
    DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
    DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS"
    Linux demboo-GE72-7RD 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2110]
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [1969:e0b1] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:11c9]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The network devices are not supported by the 4.4 kernel.

The easiest solution is to do a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.2 that will be available for download soon (most likely tomorrow). It will support the wireless adapter for sure and hopefully the Ethernet one too.

Another easy solution is to install Ubuntu 16.10.

You can also install the 4.8 kernel to Ubuntu 16.04, but it is a bit more complex task without any internet connection.

Comment: Thx, 16.10 works fine! :)

Answer (score 1):

tested on mint 18.1 (16.04 LTS based)

for ethernet card open a terminal and type

```
sudo modprobe alx    
echo 1969 e0b1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/alx/new_id
```